# OO design choice and single responsibility principle

Tags: c#, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I'm currently refactoring an application which in essence periodically downloads content from various sources (http, ftp, sql, etc). There is a schedule which controls the times during which the application can be active. For example, it can download content between 8AM and 16PM. The application has been writting in an object oriented language (C#).

This is the general design I came up with in my first iteration:
[image: First iteration design]

The Scheduler class will be responsible for keeping to the general schedule. It starts the downloading at the start of the scheduled period, and stops it at the end. The Scheduler contains a number of ITask implementations, each of which have their own bit of downloading to do. I've created an abstract base class implementation which periodically calls the protected abstract method "StartDownload". Subclasses of Task will only implement this method, and won't have to worry about timing and scheduling.

So far, so good. But while TDD'ing the Task baseclass, I realised that it was actually difficult to mock the behaviour of StartDownload. When the Task's timer ticks, it should only call StartDownload if it has finished the previous download iteration. But since these are implementation details, it's hard to mock.

This made me wonder if the Task class isn't actually violating the Single Responsibility Principle. After all, it's taking care of the periodical invocation of StartDownload. And the StartDownload method is responsible for the actual downloading. So I came up with a more separated design:
[image: Second iteration design]

Here the responsibility of the Task class is limited to just periodically calling the Client. And the Client's only responsibility is downloading content. Testing the Task class will now be easier, because I can just inject an IDownloadClient mock.

I do wonder if this is actually a clearer design though... The Task class now seems a bit odd, being just a single implementation without any subclasses. What do you guys think?

Comment: This question fits best to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ah yes, I remembered there was something like that, but I couldn't find it. I'll put it up over there, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The Scheduler contains a number of ITask implementations, each of
>   which have their own bit of downloading to do.

I think you are mixing two objects, which I would name Task and Download. May each Task perform several Downloads? In that case your second design is more appropriate but I'm missing an aggregation relationship between Task and IDownloadClient.

If each Task accounts for just one Download, then I'd refactor the first design making sure that the Scheduler actually handles all the Tasks - I mean, what do LastDownload and NextDownload represent?

Comment: The Task and Download have a 1 to 1 relationship. So each Task performs one Download, so to speak.
How would you refactor the first design though? In practice, all Task instances will be added to a single Scheduler instance and started/stopped from there.

Comment: @PJanssen the logic that you've described for your `Task` abstract base class sounds like something the `Scheduler` should be responsible for. It should be him **scheduling** the starts/stops and keeping track of Last/NextDownload.

Comment: Yes I've considered that too. Then the logic of Task in the second design (i.e. periodically calling a method) will be included in Scheduler. It would have to keep a collection of timer objects and manage those, because Tasks may run at different intervals. That might make it more difficult to hook it into a UI, which is what I would like to do eventually.